# Discrete X Labels in ggplot2 do not end

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data taken from a Likert Survey. The scale of the survey is from 1 to 5. I am calculating the percentage of responses chosen for each question. My problem is when graphing these percentages, the boundary of the x-axis seems endless.  This is the code I'm using to plot:

```
#Get the proportion table for the factored responses and melt it using the reshape2 package
#Graph it using the factor levels for X and the value converted into percentage for y

ggplot(melt(prop.table(table(factor(jsp.df$Q1, 
    levels =c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))))),
    aes(x=Var1, y=value*100)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
labs(title = "Q1: Deaf People Will be in College\n", x = "\nLikert Factors\n", y="Percent Circled\n") +
ylim(c(0,100)) +

#Replace factor levels with label names
scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), labels=c("Very Good \nChance", "Fairly Good \nChance", "Some \nChance", "A Little \nChance", "No \nChance"))
```

The results are attached.  What would be the best way to fix the x axis?  Thank you

[image: Results]

Comment: Could we get access to this data?

Comment: Unfortunately, the data itself is confidential. I need to teach myself how to generate random data for the purposes of making questions like these.

Comment: Jon, I meant cooked-up data.. to work with something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After melting your data of `prop.table()` `Var1` values are integers not the factors because levels are 1,2,.... So in `ggplot()` call you need to use `scale_x_continuous()` instead of `scale_x_discrete()`.

```
+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                   labels=c("Very Good \nChance", "Fairly Good \nChance", 
                          "Some \nChance", "A Little \nChance", "No \nChance"))
```

Another way is to set `limits=` inside the `scale_x_discrete()`. For l`imits=` you should use the same values as for `breaks=`.

```
+ scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), limits=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   labels=c("Very Good \nChance", "Fairly Good \nChance", 
                      "Some \nChance", "A Little \nChance", "No \nChance"))
```

Comment: Would `+xlim(c(0.5, 5.5))` have succeeded?

Comment: @DWin together with scale_x_discrete() it won't work because it adds "another scale for x"

Comment: Thank you, Didzis.  I would upvote you, but I lost two rep with this question and dipped below 15 rep.